Multiple looping with config file in bash
I want to copy latest file based on filename in (filename_config) & in each directory based on config file (dir_config) to backup directory.
In one directory could have > 1 filename to be copy.
dir_config:
/XXX/DIR1
/XXX/DIR2
/XXX/DIRB
/XXX/DIRY7

filename_config:
ABCD
123AB
E142

However my bash script it only copy 1 filename to the backup directory even though in the dir_config having multiple filename to be copy.
Example Output:
[Wed Jul 10 13:55:09 UTC 2024]   Copy latest file from /srv/XXX/DIR1/12-ABCD_1.0_20231103082747609.zip to /srv/backup_data/XXX/DIR1
[Wed Jul 10 13:55:09 UTC 2024]   Copy latest file from /srv/XXX/DIR2/E142_1.0_20231103082747609.tar to /srv/backup_data/XXX/DIR2
[Wed Jul 10 13:55:09 UTC 2024]   Copy latest file from /srv/XXX/DIRB/17-ABCD_1.0_20231103082747609.tar to /srv/backup_data/XXX/DIRB
[Wed Jul 10 13:55:09 UTC 2024]   Copy latest file from /srv/XXX/DIRY7/XY-123AB_1.0_20231103082747609.csv to /srv/backup_data/XXX/DIRY7

This my script:
for i in $(<$dir_config)
do
    cd $Source_Dir
    
    for y in $(<$filename_config)
    do
        latest_file=$(LC_ALL=C ls $i *$y* -cr  | tail -1)
    done
    
    cp "$Source_Dir$i/$latest_file" $Backup_Dir$i
    WriteLog "Copy latest file from $Source_Dir$i/$latest_file to $Backup_Dir$i "
    
done

I'm expecting as below:
Output:
[Wed Jul 10 13:55:09 UTC 2024]   Copy latest file from /srv/XXX/DIR1/12-ABCD_1.0_20231103082747609.zip to /srv/backup_data/XXX/DIR1
[Wed Jul 10 13:55:09 UTC 2024]   Copy latest file from /srv/XXX/DIR1/E142_1.0_20231103082747601.zip to /srv/backup_data/XXX/DIR1
[Wed Jul 10 13:55:09 UTC 2024]   Copy latest file from /srv/XXX/DIR1/ZA-123AB_1.0_20231103082747601.zip to /srv/backup_data/XXX/DIR1
[Wed Jul 10 13:55:09 UTC 2024]   Copy latest file from /srv/XXX/DIR2/E142_1.0_20231103082747607.tar to /srv/backup_data/XXX/DIR2
[Wed Jul 10 13:55:09 UTC 2024]   Copy latest file from /srv/XXX/DIR2/12-ABCD_1.0_20231103082747602.tar to /srv/backup_data/XXX/DIR2
[Wed Jul 10 13:55:09 UTC 2024]   Copy latest file from /srv/XXX/DIRB/17-ABCD_1.0_20231103082747604.tar to /srv/backup_data/XXX/DIRB
[Wed Jul 10 13:55:09 UTC 2024]   Copy latest file from /srv/XXX/DIRY7/XY-123AB_1.0_20231103082747605.csv to /srv/backup_data/XXX/DIRY7


Shouldn't ls $i *$y* be ls $i/*$y*? Also, you should quote all your variables. And use while read i rather than for i in $(<filename) in case there are spaces in the names.

The -c seems to imply that you're not just looking for file names. If you could edit the question and show some samples of the file names and explain how can you tell the new files from the old, that would help more folks to understand, also see shellcheck  for validation/recommendation

@Barmar thanks for ur advise after change to this ls $i/$y the script work as expected :)

Your script is pretty fishy: You do a cd $Source_Dir wiithout cd'ing back. You don't say what is stored in the variable, but if it is a relative directory path, the cd will work well in the first iteration, but not in the subsequent ones. Further, you do later on cp "$Source_Dir$i/$latest_file" $Backup_Dir$i; again, this would fail for  a relative directory path. Currently you have an absolute path, so this doesn't harm, but it will bite you sooner or later.

In addition, don't use ls, unless you have a pretty clear picture of what filenames you possibly can expect. See here for more information. Finally, your code would break if either BackupDir or i  has a space in its name.

Making a few assumptions - given that

$Source_Dir, $filename_config, and $dir_config are being set with relevant full or relative paths,
/XXX/ is always the same $Source_Dir,
dir_config does NOT have full pathnames, but subfolders of $Source_Dir,
each $Source_Dir might have several matches from filename_config
WriteLog is a function or something that you defined elsewhere

then refactor a bit.
while read -r d 
do while read -r f 
   do  read -r x x x latest < <( 
         stat -c "%z %n" "$Source_Dir/$d"/*"$f"* | sort -nr ) || continue
       cp -put "$Backup_Dir/$d/" "$Source_Dir/$d/$latest"
       WriteLog "$Source_Dir/$d/$latest => $Backup_Dir/$d/"
   done < "$filename_config"
done < "$dir_config"

This doesn't care where it's run and doesn't need to change directories, assuming you are setting $Source_Dir, $filename_config, and $dir_config with relevant full or relative paths.
It doesn't try to parse ls, quotes all the vars, preserves file attributes, doesn't bother copying files that aren't newer than one with the same name already in the $Backup_Dir's matching subfolder, and doesn't try to copy a file if it didn't exist in the $Source_Dir's subdirectory, though it will report the error if one is missing.
Easy to do if you'd rather check that and skip the error messages, but please don't just throw the errors to the bitbucket...
Note that I put the copy inside the loop that reads $filename_config. If a single directory ever had files that matched more than one of your listed patterns you were only getting the last one - Look at this example I set up.
$: ls -l
total 1
-rw-r--r-- 1 P2759474 1049089 8 Jul 11 09:49 filename_config
-rw-r--r-- 1 P2759474 1049089 0 Jul 11 09:48 foobar1
-rw-r--r-- 1 P2759474 1049089 0 Jul 11 09:48 foobar2
-rw-r--r-- 1 P2759474 1049089 0 Jul 11 09:48 other1
-rw-r--r-- 1 P2759474 1049089 0 Jul 11 09:48 other2

$: echo "$filename_config:"; cat $filename_config
filename_config:
foo
her

$: for y in $(<$filename_config); do  latest_file=$(LC_ALL=C ls $i *$y* -cr  | tail -1); echo "$latest_file"; done
foobar2
other2

$: echo "cp $latest_file \$somewhere"
cp other2 $somewhere

This is what your code is doing. It should back up foobar2, but the loop is assigning it, then moving on to the next file and overwriting it before you do the copy.
You could do it that way with an array if you want -
$: for y in $(<$filename_config); do latest_file+=( $(LC_ALL=C ls $i *$y* -cr  | tail -1) ); done
$: echo cp "${latest_file[@]}" \$somewhere
cp foobar2 other2 $somewhere

Not an issue if a given directory can only have one match, but then if that's the case why do you need two config files? If one directory always has only one match, you could set up one file with both pattern and directory and do the whole thing in one loop.

Hi @Paul Hodges, all ur assumptions is correct, also yes WriteLog function I'm create for the output in logfile. Thanks for ur clear explanation i will try to do some adaptation it :)

I have try this while read -r d  & working perfectly, thanks :)

Very glad I could help. :) Consider upvoting any (all!) solutions that provide useful insight and/or teach you something.  tripleee called out a very important point that I didn't actually explicitly mention, though I fixed it in my version. Worth some love for that loo!

Your question is rather unclear; but if you want to copy the latest file for each pattern in the config file, you need to put the cp inside the loop. Currently, you are simply setting latest_file successively to the latest file for each pattern in the config file (except see below), and then immediately forgetting and replacing it with the result for the next pattern, ending up only copying the latest file (ostensibly for the last pattern in the file, but again see the next paragraph).
Furthermore, ls $i *$y* will look for all files in $i and any file in the current working directory matching *$y*. I'm guessing you really mean ls "$i"/*"$y"* but you should probably review this.
Also, don't read lines with for  and quote your variables.
while read -r i
do    
    while read -r y
    do
        latest_file=$(LC_ALL=C ls -cr "$i"/*"$y"* | tail -1)
    done<"$filename_config
    
    cp "$Source_Dir$i/$latest_file" "$Backup_Dir$i"
    WriteLog "Copy latest file from $Source_Dir$i/$latest_file to $Backup_Dir$i"
    
done<"$dir_config"

A more thorough rewrite would also avoid ls in scripts and probably read the pattern file once into an array before the main loop, instead of inefficiently rereading the same data from disk over and over again. (Granted, it will probably be reasonably fast for a small file with modern caching.)
I removed cd "$Source_Dir" entirely in response to a comment, as it didn't seem to do anything useful. What exactly works and how exactly it works also depends on whether these are absolute or relative paths, but we can't see what these variables contain. Perhaps see also What exactly is current working directory?

May I suggest moving cd "$Source_Dir" to outside the loop, and remove its reference from the cp command?

Thanks. Actually, I removed it entirely.

Removing it completely is dangerous.  The calculation of latest_filewould fail then, if i is a relative path.

Yeah, my commentary on this change highlights that already.
